# Create Html Tree view with native javascript / HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create an HTML/CSS tree view as in the example from already created object using native javascript.

Please suggest,

BR

Comment: you asked the same question today.

Comment: So do you have an answer , for generating the html tree :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first build nested structure and then use recursive approach to also create html from that data where if the current element has children property you call the function again with that children array as a data parameter.

```js
var data = [{"name":"container-1","type":"container","description":"container description"},{"name":"category-1","type":"category","parent":"container-1"},{"name":"grid-1","type":"grid","parent":"category-1"},{"name":"chart-1","type":"chart","parent":"category-1"},{"name":"container-2","type":"container"},{"name":"category-2","type":"category","parent":"container-2"},{"name":"category-3","type":"category","parent":"container-2"},{"name":"grid-2","type":"grid","parent":"category-2"},{"name":"chart-2","type":"chart","parent":"category-2"},{"name":"grid-3","type":"grid","parent":"category-3"}]

function toTree(data, pid = undefined) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (pid == e.parent) {
      const obj = { ...e }
      const children = toTree(data, e.name)
      if (children.length) obj.children = children;
      r.push(obj)
    }

    return r
  }, [])
}

function toHtml(data, isRoot = true) {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul')

  if (!isRoot) {
    ul.classList.add('hide')
  }

  data.forEach(e => {
    let isVisible = isRoot;
    const li = document.createElement('li')
    const text = document.createElement('span')
    const button = document.createElement('button')

    if (e.children) {
      button.textContent = '+'
      li.appendChild(button)
    }

    text.textContent = e.name
    li.appendChild(text)

    if (e.children) {
      const children = toHtml(e.children, false)
      li.appendChild(children)

      button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (isRoot) {
          isVisible = !isVisible
        }

        button.textContent = isVisible ? '+' : '-'
        children.classList.toggle('hide')

        if (!isRoot) {
          isVisible = !isVisible
        }
      })
    }

    ul.appendChild(li)

  })

  return ul;
}

const tree = toTree(data)
const html = toHtml(tree)

document.body.appendChild(html)
```

```css
.hide {
   display: none;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Nenad Vracar , but i need it with +/- , means when press + it expands the relevant node. Same for - , minimize the content. As in the 1st picture

Comment: You can try `const obj = Object.assign({}, e)` instead